# In R, what is the difference between the function"print" and "show"?

Tags: r, printing, show

When I read a book named 《Introduction to Scientific Programming and Simulation Using R》, I was confused by the usage of "print" and "show". It said if you use function "show" in your code, then when you call "source" to carry out the code again, the function "show" will not work. Instead, if you use "print" in your code, then it works fine when you "source" it.

I try to find the reason why it is, but only to find most people focus more about the difference between the "cat" and "show", so could anyone tell me the difference between "show" and "print" and in practice, when should I use show and when should use the other?

Comment: One difference i know: `a<-print(mtcars)` , `b <-show(mtcars)`. You can see `b` is `NULL` where `a` gets `mtcars` assigned.

Comment: I think its not worth spending too much time on it.

Comment: Yeah, maybe "print" can return an object while "show" can not. It helps, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In R, there are two object oriented programming frameworks: the simple, but not formalized S3 framework, and the complex, but formalized S4 framework. In both frameworks, if you call a *generic* function such as `print`, the actual work is done by another function, specifically crafted for the type of object you are trying to print. For example, if you call `print(df)`, and `df` is a data.frame, the actual printing will be done by the function `print.data.frame`. This is called method dispatching. If not specific method is found, then `print.default` is used.

Basically, you can understand `show` as the generalization of `print` for S4 classes. `show` takes a look at an object, and if it is an S4 class object, it calls the respective S4 method defined by the object signature. If it is an S3 object, it dispatches to the relevant `print` method.

It is true that `show` usually does not return a value, but whether `show` or `print` returns a value or not depends on the particular function that gets called. The `base::print...` methods all return the object invisibly, and the `show` methods return invisibly a NULL, but it is a convention rather than a requirement.